# VB Excel Paste/Pastespecial doesn't paste formulas, or it pastes a row as an object

Tags: excel, vb.net, copy, paste

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0HJK.jpg)I'm trying to copy a row that contains formulas and values and maybe other parameters, but when using PasteSpecial PasteAll , it pastes it as objects one of top of each other that can be dragged like an image on the sheet. Also tried to used the other parameters of pastespecial like xlFormulasandValues..
When I try to use just the Paste method or it doesn't copy the formulas and I get the message shown in the attached image.
Any Idea?

```
lastEmptyRowInNewFile = xlNewSh.Cells(xlNewSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1
xlCurSh.Rows(isFound.Row.ToString() & ":" & isFound.Row.ToString()).Copy()
xlNewSh.Paste(xlNewSh.Range("A" & lastEmptyRowInNewFile.ToString()))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to copy data from one workbook sheet to another workbook sheet (or to be exact - a new workbook sheet). What I tried to do is to use the .Copy() method of a range in the source sheet and paste it  in the new sheet with the PasteSpecial method. The problem I encountered with the PasteSpecial is that it pasted the data not in the target cell, but as objects (like an image of the data ) line by line on top of each other. These objects are draggable.  When I used the .Paste or targetRange.value=sourceValue it didn't copy the formulas inside the cells.

Comment: How can I copy the data from the source to the target sheet formatted, formulas and values? the PasteSpecial .Value, .Paste don't work. Hope I explained correctly

Comment: Anyone please help?